# How to update UI according to ICollectionView filter results?

Tags: wpf, icollectionview

I have two controls - `SearchFilter` and `SearchResult`. Filter contains buttons with commands to filter results. Result control has a `ListView` with a binding to `ICollectionView` property.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SearchList}">
```

my modelview with filter logic:

```
private void FilterTheResults()
{
    var list = (ListCollectionView) SearchList;
    list.Filter = x => ((SearchItem)x).Type == "Video";
}
```

The problem is as follows:
If I move buttons with commands from the filter control to the result one, my UI is updated after each filter action. But I want to keep these things separate. I have tried to use `SearchList.Refresh()` and `PropertyChanged` in `FilterTheResults()` without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Editor's note: @Yevhen Martynov edited the answer he found into his question. I put it here as an answer instead.</sup>

The solution is the one instance of viewmodel for both controls (through `DataContext` of `Window`).

Comment: The system notified me that I need to wait 5 hours to answer myself. Thanks for help.